.NET Core 8.0 on IIS: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Cannot marshal managed types when the runtime marshalling system is disabled
I'm getting this exception that I put bellow, while I tried to start my ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API on my IIS site.

AgentStatus=Failed (Initializing), AD=Shared Domain1
Failed to initialize agent: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1':
Cannot marshal managed types when the runtime marshalling system is disabled.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.get_Environment()
at Program.$(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 16

Application Pool:

Web.config:

.NET Core info:


It seems you have installed Dynatrace in your server. Please try to disable the rules( or stop this Dynatrace), then test again.

Hi amoncada, may I know if you have a chance to check below answer ?

Hello @JasonPan, Yes,  you were right in the first comment. We had to modify the rules of the main server from which the configurations are inherited.

From the exception message, the IIS sites were protected/monitored by 3rd software (Dynatrace).
Make sure the rules in Dynatrace are correct.
